# Discord.js Pagination Limit

Tags: discord.js

Basically I'm trying to create a pagination limit per embed, So if there are 10+ values then there would be separate embeds per 10. So far I was doing, But it just spams it and doesn't work any ideas?

```
 const pages = []
    const result = []
    const limit = 10;
console.log(result.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if(limit >= result.length){
            
            let reactionhistry = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(result)
            pages.push(reactionhistry)
            paginationEmbed(message, pages)
        }
    }
```